# Bluestacks и Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

У меня есть эмулятор Android Bluestacks. Я хочу тестировать свои программы на нем. Как это сделать?

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Его не видит студия или что?

Comment: Не появляется в студии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Запустите BlueStack
2. Закройте AndroidStudio
3. Выполните в консоли `adb connect localhost:5555`

После этих действий можно будет запустить AndroidStudio  и при нажатии на Run обнаружиться BlueStack.

Comment: Закрыл Android Studio. Открыл BlueStack. Зашел в консоль и ввел `adb connect localhost:5555` после нажал на Enter и внизу такая строка `"unable to connect to localhost:5555: cannot connect to localhost:5555: Подключение не установлена, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение. <10061>"` Что это значит и как это решить?

Comment: @akmaltilloev сделайте adb tcpip 5555после пункта 2

Comment: В этот раз `error: no devices/emulators found`. Это может быть связано, с тем что я не использую `adb.exe` от `SDK`, а использую `adb.exe` который сам скачaл.

Comment: @akmaltilloev a bluestack запущен?

Comment: да BlueStack запущен

Comment: @akmaltilloev попробуйте тогда повторить https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hU6h1rBvJU

Comment: Когда подключаю смартфон через USB-кабель на ПК, то оно проходит удачно. А когда отключаю то неудачно.

Comment: Ок. Завтра отпишусь.

Comment: Не помоглo. Может проблема в другом?